# How can I edit the same two lines in multiple files in sequential order?

Tags: macos, perl, terminal, metadata, bulkupdate

I have a set of metadata where I need to edit the fields with a sequential number

- Line 2 on each:

  ```
  "name": "#1"
  ```
- Line 5 on each:

  ```
  "edition": 1,
  ```

I need to replace 1 on each line with sequential numbers in 580 files.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

1.json

```
{
  "name": "#1",
  "description": "description",
  "image": "imagelink",
  "edition": 1,
```

2.json

```
{
  "name": "#2",
  "description": "description",
  "image": "imagelink",
  "edition": 2,
```

3.json

```
{
  "name": "#3",
  "description": "description",
  "image": "imagelink",
  "edition": 3,
```

etc

I am trying to modify the code here to work for my scenario:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508423/add-a-sequential-number-in-a-particular-line-for-multiple-files

I tried

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = sprintf("name": %01d %s", ++$n, $_) if $. == 1; close ARGV if eof' *.json
```

When I try this I dont get any change in any of the files.

Comment: What problem are you having? It's simply a question of doing the following in a loop: read and decode a file, increment the counter, edit the fields, encode and write.

Comment: I am a total newbie when it comes to scripting. I think this can be accomplished with perl but I am not sure where to start

Comment: @ikegami - The issue is that all 580 files currently have the values in Line 2 and Line 5 set to 1 and I need to change them to sequential numbers for each file

Comment: No, that's not an issue. That's what you need to do. And I've already outlined the steps you need to take. But you're just asking us to write the code for you. SO is not a code writing service. What is it you have that doesn't work, or what it is you don't know how to do?

Comment: OK so the code I have tried to use probably is incorrect but this is what I found in searches for this issue: 

perl -pi -e '$_ = sprintf("name": %01d %s", ++$n, $_) if $. == 1; 
             close ARGV if eof' *.json
When I try this I dont get any change in any of the files

Comment: This should be in you question. Add this to your question. Show what output you did get. (It produces a compile-time error message.)

Comment: @ikegami - I took a few more stabs at this but really not getting anywhere. Added my code in edit

Comment: Start by using a JSON library instead of thinking in terms of lines.

Comment: Are the files actually named 1, 2, 3... 580?

Comment: Yes 1.json 2.json and so on

Answer (score 3):

It's always easier and more robust to use an approach that actually understands JSON when working with the format. The following uses a couple of non-core modules, [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) and [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) (If you're using homebrew for Mac package management, I don't see them available but you can install [`cpanminus`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cpanminus) and then do a `cpanm Path::Tiny JSON::MaybeXS` to install them.)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Path::Tiny;
use JSON::MaybeXS;

my $json = JSON::MaybeXS->new->utf8->pretty;
# For each file matching the RE in the current directory
foreach my $file (path(".")->children(qr/^\d+\.json$/)) {
  say "File $file";
  # Calculate the number based on the filename and update the JSON
  # object in-place
  $file->edit_raw(sub {
                    my $num = $file->basename(".json");
                    my $obj = $json->decode($_);
                    $obj->{name} = "#$num";
                    $obj->{edition} = $num + 0;
                    $_ = $json->encode($obj);
                  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code snippets solved my problem:

```
perl -pi -e 's/#1/sprintf("#". ++$n)/e' *.json(n)
```

The first addressed the issue of replacing #1 with #(sequential numbers)

```
perl -pi -e 's/: 1/sprintf(": ".++$n)/e' *.json(n)
```

The second addresses the issue of replacing : 1 (found in line 5) with :(sequential numbers)

Comment: You don't need two separate scripts for that.